# Override a method in Magento\UrlRewrite\Controller\Router class

Tags: magento2, overrides

I want to make some changes in the **getNormalizedPathInfo** method of **Magento\UrlRewrite\Controller\Router** class.

For this, I have created a module and tried to rewrite like below:

> **Step #1:** app/code/Stack/FixPagination/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\UrlRewrite\Controller\Router" type="Stream\FixPagination\Controller\Router" />
</config>
```

> **Step #2:** app/code/Stack/FixPagination/Controller/Router.php

```
<?php
namespace Stack\FixPagination\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class Router extends \Magento\UrlRewrite\Controller\Router {

    private function getNormalizedPathInfo(RequestInterface $request): string
    {
        $path = (string)$request->getPathInfo();
        if (!empty($path) && $request->getQuery()->count()) {
            $path = ltrim($path, '/'); // changed rtrim to ltrim
        }

        return $path;
    }
}
```

But my changes are not reflecting. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to override private function, you can't override it. You can use below code in your controller file.

> app/code/Stack/FixPagination/Controller/Router.php

```
<?php
namespace Stack\FixPagination\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class Router extends \Magento\UrlRewrite\Controller\Router {

    public function match(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $rewrite = $this->getRewrite(
            $this->_getNormalizedPathInfo($request),
            $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        );

        if ($rewrite === null) {
            //No rewrite rule matching current URl found, continuing with
            //processing of this URL.
            return null;
        }
        if ($rewrite->getRedirectType()) {
            //Rule requires the request to be redirected to another URL
            //and cannot be processed further.
            return $this->processRedirect($request, $rewrite);
        }
        //Rule provides actual URL that can be processed by a controller.
        $request->setAlias(
            UrlInterface::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
            $rewrite->getRequestPath()
        );
        $request->setPathInfo('/' . $rewrite->getTargetPath());
        return $this->actionFactory->create(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward::class
        );
    }

    private function _getNormalizedPathInfo(RequestInterface $request): string
    {
        $path = (string)$request->getPathInfo();
        if (!empty($path) && $request->getQuery()->count()) {
            $path = ltrim($path, '/'); // changed rtrim to ltrim
        }

        return $path;
    }
}
```

Instead of **getNormalizedPathInfo**, you can create new **_getNormalizedPathInfo**, and you can use it. This is not a best solution. But you can not override private method. Instead of overriding controller, you can create Plugin.

Change content in your `di.xml` file here

> app/code/Stack/FixPagination/etc/di.xml

Content for this file is...

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\UrlRewrite\Controller\Router">
        <plugin name="plugin_router" type="Stack\FixPagination\Plugin\RouterPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Create Plugin file here..

> app/code/Stack/FixPagination/Plugin/RouterPlugin.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php

namespace Stack\FixPagination\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class RouterPlugin extends \Magento\UrlRewrite\Controller\Router implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
{
    public function aroundMatch(\Magento\UrlRewrite\Controller\Router $router, \Closure $proceed, RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $rewrite = $router->getRewrite(
            $this->getNormalizedPathInfo($request),
            $router->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        );

        if ($rewrite === null) {
            //No rewrite rule matching current URl found, continuing with
            //processing of this URL.
            return null;
        }
        if ($rewrite->getRedirectType()) {
            //Rule requires the request to be redirected to another URL
            //and cannot be processed further.
            return $router->processRedirect($request, $rewrite);
        }
        //Rule provides actual URL that can be processed by a controller.
        $request->setAlias(
            UrlInterface::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
            $rewrite->getRequestPath()
        );
        $request->setPathInfo('/' . $rewrite->getTargetPath());
        return $router->actionFactory->create(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward::class
        );
    }

    private function getNormalizedPathInfo(RequestInterface $request): string
    {
        $path = $request->getPathInfo();
        /**
         * If request contains query params then we need to trim a slash in end of the path.
         * For example:
         * the original request is: http://my-host.com/category-url-key.html/?color=black
         * where the original path is: category-url-key.html/
         * and the result path will be: category-url-key.html
         *
         * It need to except a redirect like this:
         * http://my-host.com/category-url-key.html/?color=black => http://my-host.com/category-url-key.html
         */
        if (!empty($path) && $request->getQuery()->count()) {
            $path = rtrim($path, '/');
        }

        return (string)$path;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks, worked for me.